# Problema ao fazer deploy com capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deploy, capistrano

Estou tendo um problema bem estranho com o capistrano no momento de fazer o deploy para o meu ambiente de staging. Estou usando **Ruby 2.0.0**, **Rails 4.2.3** e **Capistrano 3.4.0**. O meu ambiente no servidor está pronto, no entanto quando eu dou um `cap staging deploy`, o processo é executado normalmente, até que recebo este erro:

`NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper`

Noto que ele está relacionado ao precompile, visto que nas linhas que antecedem o erro, eu vejo:

`Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile`

Já tentei mudar a versão do Rails para **4.2.0**, mas o problema continua acontecendo da mesma forma.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Você pode oferecer o stack trace para podermos diagnosticar?